# Using Office Interop in a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, com, office-interop

I am currently confused about things as I do not have enough knowledge on WCF. I have a service that has a method that calls the Excel Application (COM object). I am using the service to create an excel spreadsheet and format it. To format the file, I open the file from the code and execute a macro on it. It worked well on my personal laptop but on the server it gave me errors. I then installed excel on the server and things seems to be working fine. But while doing all this I stumbled upon this page on the asp.net forums. It states that Microsoft does not recommend using COM objects in webservices.

This is the link: "[Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us)"

I would like to get some insight from people who have done something similar or have some theoretical knowledge about the same.

Comment: COM incurs a ton of overhead (actual instances of Excel.exe are spawning every time you call the web service). What if I called your web service 3,000 times in 1 minute? You could bring the server down pretty quickly if the Excel instances aren't properly cleaned up. In the article, the "Problems using server-side Automation of Office" section highlights quite a few cons of automating office in a web service. I would use a library that doesn't required the installation of office and is thread-safe, like Aspose (or similar).

Comment: @Cory Yes, but it's possible to limit the number of Excel calls. Excel call requests can be put into a queue, and this queue can be processed by a separate process asynchronously.

Comment: @Cory, Thanks for the reply. I get what you are saying. But my most important part of the file generation is formatting the file for which I use VBA. I am pretty naive in this and have very limited knowledge. will using solutions such as the one mentioned by you provide such features of Excel such as Grouping and SubTotals?

Comment: @Ron: Yes, it can do Grouping and SubTotals. However, Aspose can get expensive :\

Comment: It is not safe to use Office Interop from a service application like a WCF service. Those APIs were written on the assumption that they would be used from a desktop application, and running them in a service violates those assumptions.

Comment: I see you've found the article that tells you not to do this. So what's your question?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I need some advice from people who have tried implementing such things and if it is worth the try. If not I will have to go ahead with solutions that are costly as posted by Cory. I have tried using some of the third party apps and was not satisfied with what they have to offer. I would maybe need to go the way cory is suggesting with buying the costly ones that would maybe solve the  problem.

Comment: I assume using of office applications by developers is quite wide spread. Does anyone know if microsoft is working towards doing something that might be thread safe and take up much resources?

Comment: The use of Office apps thru _desktop_ apps is widespread. The expert advice is don't try this from a service. The only thing I've heard of that could work is difficult. Write an add-in in a desktop app. Host a WCF service in that app, ensuring that only one connection at a time takes place. Talk to the WCF service from your main service.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the input. My application is a winforms application and I assume the overhead of making two service calls is less than the over head of having multiple Excel objects spawn on the server. I would get data from the service and do the document part on client and give the file back to the service for further processing. Does this sound to be a good approach?

Comment: You may want to ditch the Excel Automation approach via COM and look into [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).  I have used this with great success in the past on the server.  You can do formatting too!